# Combine Twitter Bootstrap components: Dropdown and Accordion

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have a global nav element that is a drop-down menu. But instead of having a  I'd like to incorporate an accordion. I've tried combining the two, but every time I click on an element in the accordion, it toggles visibility and disappears. Though next time I open it, it shows the new accordion state. So the accordion is working, I just can't get it to stay visible.

Any thoughts?

```
<div id="map" class="dropdown-menu" style="width:200px; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0; z-index: 1000; float: left; min-width: 200px;">
    <div class="accordion " id="accordion2">
        <div class="accordion-group">
          <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
              Collapsible Group Item #1
            </a>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body " style="height: 0px; ">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
              <a href="#" class="collapse ">Tester link</a>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-group">
          <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">
              Collapsible Group Item #2
            </a>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse" style="height: 0px; ">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
              Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-group">
          <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseThree">
              Collapsible Group Item #3
            </a>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-body in" style="height: auto; ">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
              Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can we see a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 2):

By preventing the clicks on the accordion heading links to bubble down we can keep the dropdown open:

http://jsfiddle.net/JEHmK

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for that example, but how would you have the toggle button somewhere else? - When I try to move the button outside the <div class="dropdown" id="menu1">, it opens the dropdown, but clicking again doesn't close it.